# Read more link in joomla 2.5.7

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a problem with the read more link in joomla 2.5.7. After insert it, when I click on the link I can see just the following lines to the Read more link and not the full article, why?.

Thanks so much and this is the link: http://www.dasphotonics.com/apps/joomla/en/technological-capabilities/technologies.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use the Joomla CMS and not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `Show intro text` is set to `Hide` in the article options instead of 'use global' or 'show'. The proper way to add *Readmore* is this [described here](http://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more).

*Also consider updating your joomla version from 2.5.7 to the [current](http://www.joomla.org/download.html).*